# void pointers to literal constants

Tags: c, void-pointers

As I was walking through some code written by others, I came across a following sentence whose meaning I'm not sure of. Any help is appreciated.

```
str != ((void *)0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is comparing `str`, supposedly a pointer, with a `NULL` pointer, effectively.

Comment: Thanks, that's my original guess. Just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

((void *)0) is essentially the same as NULL

Technically, the NULL pointer is 0x0

So that statement is ensuring that the pointer, str, is not NULL

The compiler

Answer (score 0):

It is a redundant way of testing whether `str` is zero or non-zero.

As in this case, widespread use of `(void*)` casts in C and C++ code is often a sign that the programmer didn't really understand the language. The compiler will insert these casts in many of the cases where they are required. In this case it isn't required at all.